Wordpress retrieve post / posts including all custom fields related to it
I'm trying to build a headless cms and trying to build a graphql schema at the moment.
I was wondering is there anyway to retrieve a post including all the custom fields? at the moment I'm using CarbonFields to build the custom field if it matter.
Second question will be, can I retrieve all posts including all custom fields?
I know I can do the following
get_post($postId);
get_metadata('post', $postId);

or

get_post($postId);
carbon_get_post_meta($postId, 'customField1');
carbon_get_post_meta($postId, 'customField2');
carbon_get_post_meta($postId, 'customField3');

but doing that way seems like I'm hitting the database multiple times unless I'm mistaken, so imagine if I need to build a schema for all posts.

the call to get_metadata return all the meta value of a post in one time. if retrieving all these values from one post or all posts needs to much time, you can create a cache and and new endpoint in the api that use this cache.
